# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS has gone into READ ONLY mode after I ran ntfsfix on its partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, hard-drive, 20.04, read-only

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS has gone into READ ONLY mode. I ran `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda9` (which is definitely my Ubuntu partition).

```
Mounting volume... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... NTFS signature is missing
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
NTFS signature is missing.
Trying the alternate boot sector
Unrecoverable error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

I also ran Chkdsk and I got SELF-TEST FAILED. I have a lot of work in there and cannot even access it using USB sticks / external drives.

How can I fix this and avoid losing data?

Comment: Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110009/discussion-on-question-by-milan-ubuntu-20-04-lts-has-gone-into-read-only-mode). Feel free to continue there :)